# summing elements from a user defined datatype

Tags: f#, functional-programming, f#-interactive

Upon covering the predefined datatypes in f# (i.e lists) and how to sum elements of a list or a sequence, I'm trying to learn how I can work with user defined datatypes. Say I create a data type, call it list1:

```
type list1 = 
    A
  | B of int * list1
```

Where:

- A stands for an empty list
- B builds a new list by adding an int in front of another list

so 1,2,3,4, will be represented with the list1 value:

```
B(1, B(2, B(3, B(4, A))))
```

From the wikibook I learned that with a list I can sum the elements by doing:

```
let List.sum [1; 2; 3; 4]
```

But how do I go about summing the elements of a user defined datatype? Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I'm able to take advantage of the match operator:

```
let rec sumit (l: ilist) : int = 
  match l with
  | (B(x1, A)) -> x1
  | (B(x1, B(x2, A))) -> (x1+x2)

sumit (B(3, B(4, A)))
```

I get:

```
val it : int = 7
```

How can I make it so that if I have more than 2 ints it still sums the elemets (i.e. (B(3, B(4, B(5, A)))) gets 12?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One good general approach to questions like this is to write out your algorithm in word form or pseudocode form, then once you've figured out your algorithm, convert it to F#. In this case where you want to sum the lists, that would look like this:

The first step in figuring out an algorithm is to carefully define the specifications of the problem. I want an algorithm to sum my custom list type. What *exactly* does that mean? Or, to be more specific, what exactly does that mean for the two different kinds of values (A and B) that my custom list type can have? Well, let's look at them one at a time. If a list is of type A, then that represents an empty list, so I need to decide what the sum of an empty list should be. The most sensible value for the sum of an empty list is 0, so the rule is "I the list is of type A, then the sum is 0". Now, if the list is of type B, then what does the sum of that list mean? Well, the sum of a list of type B would be its int value, plus the sum of the sublist.

So now we have a "sum" rule for each of the two types that `list1` can have. If A, the sum is 0. If B, the sum is (value + sum of sublist). And that rule translates almost verbatim into F# code!

```
let rec sum (lst : list1) =
    match lst with
    | A -> 0
    | B (value, sublist) -> value + sum sublist
```

A couple things I want to note about this code. First, one thing you may or may not have seen before (since you seem to be an F# beginner) is the `rec` keyword. This is required when you're writing a recursive function: due to internal details in how the F# parser is implemented, if a function is going to call itself, you have to declare that ahead of time when you declare the function's name and parameters. Second, this is not the *best* way to write a `sum` function, because it is not actually tail-recursive, which means that it might throw a StackOverflowException if you try to sum a really, *really* long list. At this point in your learning F# you maybe shouldn't worry about that just yet, but eventually you will learn a useful technique for turning a non-tail-recursive function into a tail-recursive one. It involves adding an extra parameter usually called an "accumulator" (and sometimes spelled `acc` for short), and a properly tail-recursive version of the above `sum` function would have looked like this:

```
let sum (lst : list1) =
    let rec tailRecursiveSum (acc : int) (lst : list1) =
        match lst with
        | A -> acc
        | B (value, sublist) -> tailRecursiveSum (acc + value) sublist
    tailRecursiveSum 0 lst
```

If you're already at the point where you can understand this, great! If you're not at that point yet, bookmark this answer and come back to it once you've studied tail recursion, because this technique (turning a non-tail-recursive function into a tail-recursive one with the use of an inner function and an accumulator parameter) is a very valuable one that has all sorts of applications in F# programming.

Comment: Great, thank you for the spot-on explanation. Do you recommend handling the possible error `| _ -> failwith "error message"` ?

Comment: In this specific case, no I don't, because the match expression covers all possible cases of your data type. Therefore, if you added a third case C, you'd get a compiler warning in your match expression that says "Possibly unhandled case C", and you'd know that you need to fix your `sum` function. If you have a catch-all match expression like `| _ ->`, then the compiler won't warn you that C is possible unhandled, and you'll find out at runtime rather than at compiletime. This is a Bad Thing™, because errors at runtime can slip through to production code, whereas compiletime errors get caught.

Comment: The one case where the use of the catchall `| _ -> failwith "error message"` case is a good idea is if you have a match expression that you *know* doesn't cover every possible situation. For example, you might be checking user input that can only be "A", "B" or "C". You might write that as `match input with | "A" -> handleA() | "B" -> handleB() | "C" -> handleC() | _ -> failwith "Input should be A, B or C"`. In that case, the catchall clause is a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Besides tail-recursion, generic programming may be a concept of importance for the functional learner. Why go to the trouble of creating a custom data type, if it only can hold integer values?

The sum of all elements of a list can be abstracted as the repeated application of the addition operator to all elements of the list and an accumulator primed with an initial state. This can be generalized as a functional fold:

```
type 'a list1 = A | B of 'a * 'a list1
let fold folder (state : 'State) list =
    let rec loop s = function
    | A -> s
    | B(x : 'T, xs) -> loop (folder s x) xs
    loop state list 
// val fold :
//   folder:('State -> 'T -> 'State) -> state:'State -> list:'T list1 -> 'State
B(1, B(2, B(3, B(4, A))))
|> fold (+) 0
// val it : int = 10
```

Making also the `sum` function generic needs a little black magic called statically resolved type parameters. The signature isn't pretty, it essentially tells you that it expects the `(+)` operator on a type to successfully compile.

```
let inline sum xs = fold (+) Unchecked.defaultof<_> xs
// val inline sum :
//   xs: ^a list1 ->  ^b
//     when ( ^b or  ^a) : (static member ( + ) :  ^b *  ^a ->  ^b)
B(1, B(2, B(3, B(4, A))))
|> sum
// val it : int = 10
```