# How to count number of non-empty nodes in binary tree in F#

Tags: f#, binary-tree

Consider the binary tree algebraic datatype

```
type btree = Empty | Node of btree * int * btree
```

and a new datatype deﬁned as follows:

```
 type finding = NotFound | Found of int
```

Heres my code so far:

```
let s = Node (Node(Empty, 5, Node(Empty, 2, Empty)), 3, Node (Empty, 6, Empty))
(*
     (3)
    /    \
   (5)   (6)
   / \   |  \
  () (2) () ()
 / \
() ()
*)

(* size: btree -> int *)
let rec size t =
    match t with
    Empty -> false
  | Node (t1, m, t2) -> if (m != Empty) then sum+1 || (size t1) || (size t2)

let num = occurs s
printfn "There are %i nodes in the tree" num
```

This probably isn't close, I took a function that would find if an integer existed in a tree and tried changing the code for what I was trying to do.

I am very new to using F# and would appreciate any help. I am trying to count all non empty nodes in the tree. For example the tree I'm using should print the value 4.

Comment: You should probably also show us your `btree` type definition, so we can see exactly how the `Node` case is defined. That will help anyone trying to answer.

Comment: I also suggest reading the answer I gave to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52133996/summing-elements-from-a-user-defined-datatype and considering the general approach I suggested: write down every possible case of your `btree` data type and decide what value should be returned for each case. E.g., for a tree that's just an `Empty` node you'd want to return 0, because there are zero non-empty nodes in that tree. For a tree with a `Node`, you'd want the sum of (non-empty nodes in the left branch), 0 or 1 depending if the root is empty, and (non-empty nodes in the right branch). Start there.

Comment: I added the data types I am to use, thanks

Answer (score 4):

I did not run the compiler on your code, but I believe this does even compile. 
However your idea to use a pattern match in a recursive function is good.
As rmunn commented, you want to determine the number of nodes in each case:
An empty tree has no nodes, hence the result is zero.
A non-empty tree, has at least the root node plus the count of its left and right subtrees.

So something along the lines of the following should work

```
let rec size t =
    match t with
    | Empty -> 0
    | Node (t1, _, t2) -> 1 + (size t1) + (size t2)
```

The most important detail here is, that you do not need a global variable `sum` to store any intermediate values. The whole idea of a recursive function is that those intermediate values are the results of recursive calls.

As a remark, your tree in the comment should look like this, I believe.

```
(*
     (3)
    /    \
   (5)   (6)
   / \   |  \
  () (2) () ()
     / \
    () ()
*)
```

Edit: I misread the misaligned `()` as leaves of an empty tree, where in fact they are leaves of the subtree `(2)`. So it was just an ASCII art issue :-)

Comment: I would note that this solution is not tail-recursive, so it may overflow the stack for a large tree.

Answer (score 2):

Friedrich already posted a simple version of the `size` function that will work for most trees.  However, the solution is not "tail-recursive", so it can cause a Stack Overflow for large trees.  In functional programming languages like F#, recursion is often the preferred technique for things like counting and other aggregate functions.  However, recursive functions generally consume a stack frame for each recursive call.  This means that for large structures, the call stack can be exhausted before the function completes.  In order to avoid this problem, compilers can optimize functions that are considered "tail-recursive" so that they use only one stack frame regardless of how many times they recurse.  Unfortunately, this optimization cannot just be implemented for any recursive algorithm.  It requires that the recursive call be the last thing that the function does, thereby ensuring that the compiler does not have to worry about jumping back into the function after the call, allowing it to overwrite the stack frame instead of adding another one.

In order to change the `size` function to be tail-recursive, we need some way to avoid having to call it twice in the case of a non-empty node, so that the call can be the last step of the function, instead of the addition between the two calls in Friedrich's solution.  This can be accomplished using a couple different techniques, generally either using an accumulator or using Continuation Passing Style.  The simpler solution is often to use an accumulator to keep track of the total size instead of having it be the return value, while Continuation Passing Style is a more general solution that can handle more complex recursive algorithms.

In order to make an accumulator pattern work for a tree where we have to sum both the left and right sub-trees, we need some way to make one tail-call at the end of the function, while still making sure that both sub-trees are evaluated.  A simple way to do that is to also accumulate the right sub-trees in addition to the total count, so we can make subsequent tail-calls to evaluate those trees while evaluating the left sub-trees first.  That solution might look something like this:

```
let size t =
    let rec size acc ts = function
    | Empty -> 
        match ts with
        | [] -> acc
        | head :: tail -> head |> size acc tail
    | Node (t1, _, t2) -> 
        t1 |> size (acc + 1) (t2 :: ts)

    t |> size 0 []
```

This adds the `acc` parameter and the `ts` parameter to represent the total count and remaining unevaluated sub-trees.  When we hit a populated node, we evaluate the left sub-tree while adding the right sub-tree to our list of trees to evaluate later. When we hit the an empty node, we start evaluating any `ts` we've accumulated, until we have no further populated nodes or unevaluated sub-trees.  This isn't the best possible solution for computing the tree-size, and most real solutions would use Continuation Passing Style to make it tail-recusive, but that should make a good exercise as you get more familiar with the language.

Comment: I agree with everything Aaron says. Just to give more intuition for the OP: both solution perform a pre-order walk of the tree. The implementations differ indeed in performance only - and here is a caveat of functional programming. There are situations - like this one - where trying to optimise a recursive function you end up writing code that resembles an imperative program. Look at the pseudo code in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Pre-order and you will see that Aaron's code mimics the while-loop with a stack.

Comment: This is not a critique of the solution but just a reminder that there is "no free lunch" ;-)